# Angular 13 Call store dispatch Action in strore.pipie inside component

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

im working in Angular 13 and ngRxStore, inside my component i want to read my store and dispatch a new Action with data returned from my store , this is my code :

```
productState$ :Observable<ProductsState>  | null = null;

constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    
this.productState$ = this.store.pipe(
   map((state)=> state.appProductState )
   
   // here i want to dispatch action using this.store.dispatch(MyAction(currentProduct.id))
);

}
```

and this is my state object :

```
export interface ProductsState {
    currentProduct:Product | null
    errorMessage:string,
    dataState:ProductSatateEnum
}
```

anyone can guide my how i can dispatch my action correctly with data returned from store inside the pipe().

Answer (score 1):

You can `tap` the data and dispatch is using the action you defined

```
productState$ :Observable<ProductsState>  | null = null;

constructor(private store: Store<any>) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    
this.productState$ = this.store.pipe(
   map((state)=> state.appProductState),
   tap(data=> this.store.dispatch(MyAction(currentProduct.id)))));

}
```